# Remove a pattern from a string limited by delimiter or end of the string

Tags: regex

colleagues.

I'm stuck on a simple question:
I have the connection string: Server=35.237.131.8,14333; Database=Online LIMS; Trusted_Connection = No; User Id = LimsUser; Password = lims42; Pooling=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=False; **DRIVER = SQL SERVER**; LastSection = false

And I want to delete the section DRIVER. It's very simple, but there is one issue: this section can be at the end of the string: "Server=35.237.131.8,14333; Database=Online LIMS; Trusted_Connection = No; User Id = LimsUser; Password = lims42; Pooling=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=False; **DRIVER = SQL SERVER**" and delimiter ';' is missing in this case.

My current regex `(?<DriverSection>DRIVER.*?;*)(?=;|$)` match the section at the end of the string and in the middle, but in the middle it does not include the separator ';', so this character is keeping in the string after deletion: Server=35.237.131.8,14333; Database=Online LIMS; Trusted_Connection = No; User Id = LimsUser; Password = lims42; Pooling=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=False;**;** LastSection = false

And I have two ';' characters in the string, what is wrong.
So my question: is it possible to match both cases by one regex?

My current regex is available here: https://regex101.com/r/OSZKtA/1

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out

```
(?<DriverSection>DRIVER.*?;*)(?<=;|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/2CG6iw/1

Answer (score 1):

Match non-semicolons, which naturally stop at end of string anyway:

```
(?<=DRIVER = )[^;]+
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/x9j6H89ApVWznU).

- `(?<=DRIVER = )` is a *look behind*, meaning the previous characters must be `"DRIVER = "`
- `[^;]` is a *negated character class* and means any character *except* a semicolon
- `+` means one or more

---

If your language/tool (not stated in question) does not support look arounds, you can still use the "non-semicolon" approach if you match the variable name too:

```
DRIVER = [^;]+
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/mLsQtVfsEjMV2C).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but regex does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: @SergeyAlikin see edits to answer adding `DRIVER = [^;]+` as an option if look behinds are not supported by your language/tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a match with a negated character class, and then optionally match the trailing `;`

```
\b(?<DriverSection>DRIVER\s*=[^;]*;?)
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?<DriverSection>` Named group `DriverSection`

  - `DRIVER\s*=` Match DRIVER, optional whitespace chars and then `=`
  - `[^;]*` Match 1+ chars optional chars other than `;`
  - `;?` Optionally match `;`
- `)` Close the named group

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/24Ph2Z/1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works, but I'm already marked first answer as "answer".

Comment: @SergeyAlikin That is perfectly ok, but using a non greedy dot and a lookbehind like that can be quite inefficient.